# merging duplicates in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

if i have a an array like below in JS

```
lineitems : [{
    quantity : 1,
    unitPrice : 10.00,
    unitPriceLessTax: 8.33,
    SKU: 'SKU123456',
    productName: 'Blue T-Shirt'
 },
 {
    quantity : 1,
    unitPrice : 10.00,
    unitPriceLessTax: 8.33,
    SKU: 'SKU123456',
    productName: 'Blue T-Shirt'
 },
 {
    quantity : 1,
    unitPrice : 48.00,
    unitPriceLessTax: 40.00,
    SKU: 'SKU78910',
    productName: 'Red Shoes'
 }]
```

how do i conver it to look like below

```
lineitems : [{
    quantity : 2,
    unitPrice : 10.00,
    unitPriceLessTax: 8.33,
    SKU: 'SKU123456',
    productName: 'Blue T-Shirt'
 },
 {
    quantity : 1,
    unitPrice : 48.00,
    unitPriceLessTax: 40.00,
    SKU: 'SKU78910',
    productName: 'Red Shoes'
 }]
```

basically looking to merge duplicates based on SKU

Comment: please form your code for better visibility

Comment: on what you want to compare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure JS; Fast calculator;

```js
<script>
    var lineItems = [{
    quantity : 1,
    unitPrice : 10.00,
    unitPriceLessTax: 8.33,
    SKU: 'SKU123456',
    productName: 'Blue T-Shirt'
 },
 {
    quantity : 1,
    unitPrice : 10.00,
    unitPriceLessTax: 8.33,
    SKU: 'SKU123456',
    productName: 'Blue T-Shirt'
 },
 {
    quantity : 1,
    unitPrice : 48.00,
    unitPriceLessTax: 40.00,
    SKU: 'SKU78910',
    productName: 'Red Shoes'
 }];

var nl =[], i=0;
var collapse = function ()
{
    if (lineItems.length<=i) return;
    if (nl[lineItems[i].SKU])
    {
        nl[lineItems[i].SKU].quantity+=lineItems[i].quantity;
    }
    else  nl[lineItems[i].SKU]=lineItems[i];
    i++;
    //lineItems.splice(0,1);
    collapse();
};
collapse();
console.log(nl);
var newLineItems = Object.keys(nl).map(function (key) {return nl[key]});
console.log(newLineItems);
console.log('new line items');
console.log(lineItems);
</script>
```

Comment: hi Leo, could you help me with the issue i am facing? basically when i runt the code the original Array gets overritten with value so i am assumin ghtis is because we are using "return nl[key]" how can i over come the problem where original values of "lineItems" is not touched but only "nl"

Comment: i have tried assigning the lineItems to another array and used the same but it still updates the original value. i have to validate the orginal array against the new one. thanks for you help

Comment: Hi Ethan, the reason it changes the original value was due to the splice.  Now I've modified the code not to splice so it should not change the original values and should also gain some performance as we're not resizing the array any longer;

Answer (score 1):

you can use associative array:

```
var newLineItems = new Array();
$.each(lineItems, function (index) {
    if (newLineItems[this.SKU])
        newLineItems[this.SKU].quantity += this.quantity;
    else
        newLineItems[this.SKU] = this;
});
```

Comment: Use an object, not an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.prototype.forEach()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

```
var result = []
var temp = [];
lineitems.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
    if (temp[element.SKU] === undefined)
        temp[element.SKU] = element;
    else
        temp[element.SKU].quantity += element.quantity;
});
for (var items in temp){
    result.push(temp[items]);
}
```

Hope it's useful

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) is a quick way to manage your collections:

```
result = _.uniq(lineitems, "SKU");
```