# Remove duplicates from an array of objects in JavaScript But merge one field before removing the duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, array-merge

I have the following variable:

```
var allProducts = [
    {"code": 1,"name": "productA", "category": ["fruits"],...},
    {"code": 1,"name": "productA", "category": ["vegetables"],...},
    {"code": 2,"name": "productB", "category": ["meat"],...},
    ...
]
```

So the only difference between the two repeated array of objects is the `category`; where in this example `code: 1` is once mentioned with `category: ["fruits"]` and another time with `category: ["vegetables"]`. Now I want to remove the duplicate but before doing so; I would like to save all the categories of `productA` into one `category: ["fruits", "vegetables"]` so the final variable would look like this:

```
var allProductsCleaned = [ 
    {"code": 1,"name": "productA", "category": ["fruits", "vegetables"],...},
    {"code": 2,"name": "productB", "category": ["meat"]...},
    ...
]
```

Comment: I think you put wrong `object`, `key` type in the variable.
It should be like this? `var allProducts = [
{"code": 1,"name": "productA", "category": ["fruits"],...},... `

Comment: Does this answer your question? [merging duplicates in javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32630932/merging-duplicates-in-javascript-array)

Comment: Edited question as objects were not formatted correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example:

- Create an object with reduce:

  - save each object into the aggregated Object to test if "code" already added
  - if already present then merge the arrays
- transform the object back to an array with `Object.values()`

```js
const allProducts = [
    {"code": 1,"name": "productA", "category": ["fruits"]},
    {"code": 1,"name": "productA", "category": ["vegetables"]},
    {"code": 2,"name": "productB", "category": ["meat"]},
    {"code": 2,"name": "productB", "category": ["fish"]},
    {"code": 2,"name": "productB", "category": ["fish"]}
]

const output = Object.values(allProducts.reduce((aggObj, item) => {  
  if (aggObj[item.code]){
    //item already exists so merge the category arrays:
    const newArr = [...new Set([...aggObj[item.code].category, ...item.category])]
    aggObj[item.code].category = newArr;
  }else{
    //doesn't already exist:
    aggObj[item.code] = item;
  }  
  return aggObj
}, {}));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you Alex! Quick question if the product with code 1 here; have the same category  for both as `["fruits"]`; with your above code it will merge it and output the category as ` ["fruits", "fruits" ]`. Right? How can I prevent that when if the `category array` contains the word `fruit` to not merge them?

Comment: Great, See my updated answer - we can use the ES6 `new Set([iterable])` to ensure unique entries (there are other ways to do it, like using `arr.inlcudes(item)`). If my answer solved your problem please consider to mark as the accepted answer and up-vote :)

Comment: You are awesome! upvoted and accepted as answer! thank you