# My data array from my Google Ads API script request sometimes has duplicate data rows how do I merge?

Tags: javascript

Newbie question: My data array (from google ads scripts) has ~20% duplicate rows in it. How do i combine those duplicates, and their data together?

Hello,

I am a new javascript programmer using Google Ads Scripts to fetch data from our client's Google Merchant Center (product shopping ads data), process that data, then use in optimizing their campaign(s). I am using their [Shopping Performance Report api](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v14/shopping_performance_view) to report on impressions, clicks, revenue, etc. The data is pulled into a google sheet and then i wrote some javascript to process that data row by row, looking at the values and making decisions, labeling product performance into one of 8 different performance categories ('top performer', 'worst performer' etc.). At the end of that row loop, i store that row's data into a temporary array ('tempArray'). I do that for all the rows in the api report object.

My problem is the data sometimes returns two rows for the product ID. Not sure why, will ask Google. However, I need to do the following just don't know how yet:

Once the data is finished processing, I need to loop through it and combine any elements that have the same product Id AND combine their values (clicks total = duplicate 1 clicks + duplicate 2 clicks, impressions total = duplicate 1 impressions + duplicate 2 impressions).

The tempArray data looks like this (example duplicate elements):

```
[
    [shopify_US_8059591393525_43884977225973, null, Chasing Joy Hat in Khaki, 8, 0,     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, low impressions],  
    [shopify_US_8059591393525_43884977225973, null, Chasing Joy Hat in Khaki, 12094, 115, 0.009508847362328427, 36.93, 1.165053, 87.08227563, 31.698128754657517, 2.3580361665312752, 0.010130895652173913, under-index]]
```

Do I need to change the data structure to an array of objects, then use a JS array function like map or reduce? I found this article on merging duplicates but it was too complex at first glance: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/merge-and-remove-duplicates-in-javascript-array

​

Thanks in advance!

I’ve considered trying the map() function but wanted to reach out first on what some options might be.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to transform the data into an array of objects.  The basic "merge duplicate entries somehow" is covered simply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61469338/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript-but-merge-one-field-bef) using Array.reduce.  Keep in mind we don't know what the various fields in your tempArray are, so asking about clicks and impressions depends a lot on that.